# Reading list of objects from binary file

Tags: c++, binary, iteration, ifstream, ofstream

I am currently building a custom binary file for a huge list of data which will be representing some angle of movements in a game. Although i am running into a wall when trying to find a way to write all the datapoints and then reading them into a huge array or vector.

Here is how i constructed my fileformat:

```
class TestFormat {
    public:
        float   x;
        float   y;
        float   z;
};
```

And the test code for writing and reading:

```
int main()
{
    TestFormat test_1, temp;
    test_1.x = 4.6531;
    test_1.y = 4.7213;
    test_1.z = 6.1375;

    // Write
    ofstream ofs("test.bin", ios::binary);
    ofs.write((char *)&test_1, sizeof(test_1));
    ofs.close();

    // Read
    ifstream ifs("test.bin", ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char *)&temp, sizeof(temp));
    ifs.close();

    cout << temp.x << endl;
}
```

To extend this code i can just write the additional objects into the same file, but i am not sure how to load these objects back into an array afterwards.

Comment: You just wrote, then read, *one*. So do that for more than one?

Comment: Hint: if an object occupies M consecutive bytes, then and array of N such objects occupies N×M consecutive bytes.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But how do i use the `read` function to read multiple objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
  vector<TestFormat> test;
  //....
  // Read
  ifstream ifs("test.bin", ios::binary);
  while(ifs.read((char *)&temp, sizeof(temp))){
     //tmp to array
     test.push_back(TestFormat(temp));
  } 
  ifs.close();
```

Using Peter Barmettler's suggestion:

```
ifstream ifs("test.bin", ios::binary);
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
int fileSize = ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

vector<TestFormat> test(fileSize/sizeof(TestFormat)); 
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(test.data()), fileSize);
ifs.close();
```

Comment: This is a interesting solution. Although it seems like it is reading the last entry twice?

Comment: Yep. I don't know why though. But you can either ignore the duplicate, or pop it, in the case of vector usage.

Comment: Still something i do not understand with the duplicate on the last object.

Comment: I modified the while loop approach. Now, no duplicates will be read. That was happening because the **good() == false** would only happen after a fail to read. However at this point, the last **temp** would be pushed once again into the vector, before the while evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you have to entries, you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<TestFormat> temp(2);

ifstream ifs("test.bin", ios::binary);
ifs.read((char *)temp.data(), temp.size()*sizeof(TestFormat));
ifs.close();

cout << temp[1].x << endl;
```

Comment: Then something along the lines of Adriano Carafini is the way to go. Or you place the number of entries in the header of your file.